# C++ high resolution SYSTEMTIME Structure, greater than ms?

Tags: c++, api, time

I am attempting to understand the various high precision timekeeping techniques in Windows, and hooking directly into the [various APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725473(v=vs.85).aspx) with C++.

I am aware of the [QPC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms644904(v=vs.85).aspx) and know that [GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706895(v=vs.85).aspx) utilises the same techniques for high precision timestamps. However the [GetSystemTimeAsFileTime()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724397(v=vs.85).aspx) API seems to be [used by SQL Server to get its high precision timestamps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186724.aspx) (i.e. DATETIME2) which I find odd.

*Note: A very good resource is the [Acquiring high-resolution time stamps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dn553408(v=vs.85).aspx) msdn article (although it is probably more of a "paper").*

> [GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706895(v=vs.85).aspx) The
>   GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime function retrieves the current system
>   date and time with the highest possible level of precision (<1us). The
>   retrieved information is in Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) format.

My issue is that the [SYSTEMTIME structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724950(v=vs.85).aspx)

> Specifies a date and time, using individual members for the **month, day, year, weekday, hour, minute, second, and millisecond.** The time is either in coordinated universal time (UTC) or local time, depending on the function that is being called.

```
typedef struct _SYSTEMTIME {
  WORD wYear;
  WORD wMonth;
  WORD wDayOfWeek;
  WORD wDay;
  WORD wHour;
  WORD wMinute;
  WORD wSecond;
  WORD wMilliseconds;
} SYSTEMTIME, *PSYSTEMTIME;
```

only seems to have millisecond precision, the documentation for this structure comments on the wMilliseconds part of the structure:

> **wMilliseconds**
>   The millisecond. The valid values for this member are 0 through 999.

If I wish to convert a high-precision FILETIME to some kind of SYSTEMTIME structure, how can I keep the extra precision? Implementing a custom conversion from the FILETIME type seems a big undertaking?

Comment: You are missing some Windows related flag. C++11 has `<chrono>` with  [std::high_resolution_clock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock)  and POSIX has `clock_gettime` (see [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extra conversion is pretty easy - `(fileTime % 10000)` gives you what the SYSTEMTIME doesn't (in 100ns steps). So you can just use that plus a SYSTEMTIME.

Although SYSTEMTIME is mostly for UI; the original FILETIME is smaller to store and easier to work with for many purposes.

Comment: (fileTime % 10000) gives number of 100ns "ticks" beyond the last ms. Doesn't this assume there is no rounding?

Comment: Yes (which I think is what FileSystemToSystemTime does). Failing that, convert back from SystemTime to FileTime and store the signed difference.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724280(v=vs.85).aspx has a community addition saying "This function truncates towards zero, it does not round."